# update went wrong

Tags: errors, miktex, update

I updated today to the last MikTex (with the update manager). Since then I can't compile. The update ended with this error:

[image]

What can I do? I'm not a wizard and I'm lost.
Thanks

Comment: Looks bad. Can't you just reinstall from scratch? Because used packages can be downloaded automatically on the fly, the install is essentially stateless.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I had the same problem a couple of days ago. Just a question: do you have MiKTeX 64 bits?

Comment: Make a bug report at the MiKTeX issue tracker.

Comment: Yes Bernard it is MikTeX x64. I tried to deinstall MikTeX, but it was not possible the deinstaller does not work. I changed the name of the diretory and reinstalled MikTeX. It is yet worse and when I want to deinstall it i get this message: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWxK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWxK.png) How can I manually deinstall MikTeX properly (all the registry keys as well)?

Comment: As @StefanSchroeder recommend try to do a reinstallation. But before that have a look into the `%AppData%` folder if there is still a entry for MiKTeX. If so, you can delete it. Then there are no more remains.

Answer (score 1):

I've done as BigG said, I installed MikTeX just for me (not for all users). So far it was good, but then when I updated I encounter the same problem. So it is not a problem of permission. Fortunately I made a copy of the directories of MikTeX before I updated and so I could return to the version of june that has no problems. I think I will always do that before updating.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (Windows 7 - 64 bit), and I think it is a permissions issue. My installation was for all users. I uninstalled, and then installed again for all users. It was fine until I updated, then the same problem. I uninstalled again, then installed for just me, then updated and it was fine. I'll stick with this workaround, but I realise it might be a problem on multi-user machines...